# SQLite Database for Android Application for local highscores. How to open ALL data and then OVERWRITE all data?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I found a lot of examples about SQlite. I have no experience with this language, but Android recommends using this database to save things locally. I just can't solve this problem. I have the following (adapted from an example):

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }                       // I don't even need this, do I? ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scoretable (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    "Curscore INTEGER, " +
                    "Curmode INTEGER, " +
                    "Curdiff INTEGER, " +
                    "Curdate STRING);";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        //Not used
    }
}
```

In my (main) activity, I have:

```
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Other code
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
}
```

To insert data I use:

```
    String dateFormat = "dd/MM";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Curscore", score);     // score is a public integer
    values.put("Curmode", gamemode);   // gamemode is a public integer
    values.put("Curdiff", difficulty); // difficulty is a public integer
    values.put("Curdate", date);
    db.insert("scoretable", null, values);
```

**QUESTION:** *The only thing I want now is a function that retrieves all data from the "scoretable". Then I will manipulate it (I compare scores and insert the new score if it is high enough, I will be able to take care of that myself). After that I want to overwrite the old data with the new manipulated data. (10-1) Why does my current code fail to work?*

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're describing isn't used in real-life for several reasons, one of them being that you'll take up way too much memory space as the database gets larger.

If I understand your problem well, you don't even need to retrieve the data, you just have to pass the right where clause in the update method.

The below code is just a way to change the highscore to 500 if the highscore is currently lower than that in the row with playerId 5.

```
int highscore = 500;
int playerId = 5;

ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
cv.put("highscore", highscore);

String where = "id=? AND highscore<?";
String[] whereArgs = {Integer.toString(playerId), Integer.toString(minimalScore};

db.update("scoretable", cv, where , whereArgs);
```

If you really need to do calculations on the data in the database, you need to query it first using db.query(). You'll get a cursor over which you can iterate. This cursor reads that database but doesn't store all the values. You can retrieve all the information you need from it and you can then do the appropriate update statements.

To delete for example all scores below 100, you can do the following.

```
int lowestAllowableScore = 100;

db.delete("scoretable", "score<?", new String[] {Integer.toString(lowestAllowableScore)});
```

edit//

You can use the android insert method for that:

Note that I used no capital letters to start variables.

```
ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("score", curscore); // We want to put curscore in the new row in the score column
    value.put("mode", curmode);
    value.put("diff", curdiff);
    value.put("date", curdate);
db.insert("scoretable",null,value);
```

You should take a look at the sqlite documentation for insert statements. With the android methods, there is no need to make real SQL code.

Comment: I indeed want to update the database when the new score is higher than the lowest score that still fits into the "high-score-screen". I just thought it would be easier to load all data, then manipulate it, and then save it back. (Problem is that all tutorials on internet use the "execSQL" command, which I do not understand at all). I will try to get this working and come back here.

Comment: I'm using the specific method that android provides to update rows. You could use execSQL to, but then you would have to type the whole SQL statement yourself. execSQL() can be used to do any non-SELECT statement. The method I'm proposing just takes the statement building out of your hands and concentrates on the logic of your application. Let me know if you're encountering any problems.

Comment: I now see what the code does. It checks for the score of the player with player ID 5, and when the score (500) is higher than its previous, it will overwrite that. It is not exactly what I want. I want the player to fill in its name after the game (if its score was high enough). It will compare the score with the scores already in the list, and put it below the scores that are higher and above the scores that are lower. P.S. For my knowledge: The "id=? AND highscore<?" statement, what "language" belongs it to?

Comment: You can just add the score to the database without comparing anything. Ordering things is for when you retrieve the data. If you want to show the data and retrieve it you just add an ORDER BY clause and the user will see everything in the right order. (Highest score at the top). The ? is just part of a SQL prepared statement.

Comment: But if you store all the data, your database will grow each time you play a game? I know this probably will not take a lot of storage room, but it sounds logical to me that you will delete data that will not be used anymore (Example: Save the top 5 scores, delete the rest because it will not be displayed). P.S. I have no time anymore to work on my project today. Will try to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: That is why I used the update function. update() replaces the row with the data and replaces the score from for example 300 to 500 in my example. You don't get any extra rows, the value is just changed. Look at it like changing a value in an excel row, not like adding an extra row. Adding an extra row (like adding an extra player for example) requires the insert() function. (And for performance to be an issue, you'll need more than a few million players. Databases are designed to hold multiple millions of rows.)

Comment: If you want to delete lower scores, you'll need to use the delete function. I'll edit my post with an example.

Comment: @ J. Maes (and others): I hope someone is still around... I took all information into consideration (edited original question). I guess I will just save the date (since the SQL can contain millions, no need to delete stjff) with score, gamemode, difficulty and current data. Is my execSQL correct? And one last question, this cursor has so many inputs... How do I get it so that when the cursor points at the first ID (=0), it will take out the entire row? I know this maybe sounds like lazyness, but all these different inputs for the query command make my head spin...

Comment: Ok, I try to put stuff into my database. It just doesn't work: Edited main file to show what my code is... It keeps giving this error: -----> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table scoretable has no column named Curdiff: , while compiling: INSERT INTO scoretable(Curdiff, Curmode, Curscore, Curdate) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);

Comment: Check my edit :) In this case you don't need question marks. You can also use the easy android method to insert.

Comment: curscore is the name of the column (tried it with capitcal letters, because without it did not work either) and score is the integer. curdate is the column name and date is a string with the date. Looking at your comment behind score, my adjusted code (see question) would be correct, right? Shouldn't it be: "// We want to put score in the new row in the curscore column" Is my creation of my table SQL code maybe wrong? I see so many examples, and they all do it different.

Comment: 01-10 23:13:22.701: I/Database(862): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table scoretable has no column named curdiff 01-10 23:13:22.722: E/Database(862): Error inserting curdiff=1 curscore=1 curdate=10/01 curmode=1 01-10 23:13:22.722: E/Database(862): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table scoretable has no column named curdiff: , while compiling: INSERT INTO scoretable(curdiff, curscore, curdate, curmode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
01-10 23:13:22.722: E/Database(862):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method) ETC.ETC.ETC.

Comment: Uninstall your application from your device, your database is not recreated. That's why the table is not recognized. If you do this your database will be recreated and your insert will hopefully succeed or you'll at least be a step closer.

Comment: YEP! That was the problem... And I did remove data + uninstalled the app, but apparently that was not enough... Making a new emulator + "wipe user data" was. No errors related to the database (except this: 01-11 00:01:19.962: E/ThrottleService(77): Error reading data file ), but it is not related to my app, right? THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP! Now I only have to show the data I saved to the screen =)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) class to retrieve all rows from the highscores table, this will give you a [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object over which you can loop. You can use the [`update()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), [`replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) and [`delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) methods to perform the needed manipulations.

Comment: @ Jan-Henk: If I check the cursor correctly, I can retrieve the data as "Arrays", each holding a "name", "score" and "gamemode". I should be something like:
Cursor tmpcursor = db.query("scoretable",null,null,null,GroupBy???,null,null,null);
Then I let the cursor move from the first "data" in the table to the "last", saving them in an array over the loop? Is that correct?

Comment: For an example of how you can use a cursor see this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying Especially the section titled reading retrieved data. This article is about content providers, but using an sqlite database is similar.